# How to understand the container of yarn correctlly?

Tags: java, hadoop, containers, hadoop-yarn

I'm so confused by the concept of container in yarn, I wonder whether the container is already determined before schedule or not? or that it is created dynamicly when request reach ? or that it is initialized well when the nodemanager start? whether the size of container is fixed accross the config or not ? ie. accorss the requirement by the AM?
I have so many question and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container represent a resource on a single node.

- It is supervised by Node Manager
- Scheduled by Resource Manager

The resource represented by container include things like RAM it is going to need, Clock cycle of CPU, disk space etc. in short all the resources that are required for executing an MR job.

It is resource manager which creates a container on the request from application master. So when we submit a Map Reduce job, it is application master on that node on which map task or reduce task is going to run determines the resource requirements and then it send a request to resource manager for allocating a container of required resources on that node, then resource manager check for its possibilities and once it is satisfied it will allocate the container now application master will take that container (container actually here is just the information about the required resource) to node manager. Node manager will then create this container and finally, our job will be executed in it.

Now coming to your question although I am sure I have answered most of them by now,

No container are not determined before scheduling although it is not clear about which scheduling you are talking but I am assuming it is one when we submit a job.

Yes they are created dynamically again it is unclear about which request you are talking but I think I have answered on which request it is created,it's the one from application master to resource manager

No, Size of container is not fixed. It depends on your Map Reduce job.

I hope this answers all your query
But still, **I will strongly suggest** you to visit [this link](http://javacrunch.in/Yarn.jsp) so that it will be more clearer to you. 
Let me know if you still have any query.

Comment: Thank you very much and your answer solve my confuse perfectly!